# Django is_valid() always returns false error

Tags: django, django-models, django-forms, django-templates, django-views

I am beginner of Django. When i submit in the html page, is_valid funtion in my views.py always returns false. users.html is my template. I obviously filled things correctly but it still returns false.
Any help would be welcome.

this is my models.py file

```
    from django.db import models

# Create your models here.
class User(models.Model):
    first_name = models.CharField(max_length=264, )
    last_name = models.CharField(max_length=264, )
    email = models.EmailField(max_length=255,)
    def __str__(self):
        return self.first_name + self.last_name
```

this is my forms.py file

```
    from django import forms
from first_app.models import User
from django.forms import ModelForm


class User_form(ModelForm):

    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = ['first_name','last_name','email']
```

this is my views.py file

```
 from django.shortcuts import render
from django.http import HttpResponse
from . import forms
from first_app.models import User
# Create your views here.

def index(request):
    return render(request,'index.html')



def user_form_view(request):

    form = forms.User_form()

    if request.method == 'POST':

        if form.is_valid():
            form = forms.User_form(request.post)
            form.save()
            return index(request)

        else:
            print(form)
            return user_show(request)

    return render(request,'first_app/users.html',{'form':form})
```

and this is my users.html

```
  <!DOCTYPE html>
{% load static %}

<html lang="en" dir="ltr">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Users</title>
  </head>
  <body>

    <h1>Hello! please type in your information</h1>
    <div class="container">

      <form class="" method="POST">
        {{form.as_p}}
        {% csrf_token %}
        <input type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" value="submit">
      </form>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: A form without data (so no `request.POST`) is always invalid, since it is not "bound".

Answer (score 1):

In order for a form to be valid, it needs to be "bounded" (you can check this with [**`.is_bounded`** [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/forms/api/#django.forms.Form.is_bound)). Bounded means that you passed data to it, for example with `request.POST` (or `request.GET`, or another dictionary-like container):

```
def user_form_view(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = forms.User_form(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            form.save()
            return index(request)
        else:
            print(form)
            return user_show(request)
    else:
        form = forms.User_form()
    return render(request,'first_app/users.html',{'form':form})
```

> **Note**: the names of classes are typically written in *PerlCase*, not *snake_case*, so you probably should rename <s>`User_form`</s> to `UserForm`.

Comment: ah i finally got it!
Thanks a lot